# How to remove padding/margin on h tags?

Tags: typography, webfonts

I'm 99% sure I'm not overlooking something here. I have the usual resets done, no margin or padding on the h tag, line-height:100% etc etc. but STILL there are about 2 or 3px padding above and below the h tags. It's the same on most major sites, so I'm guessing it's prob unavoidable? It may seem like a moot point, but it's SLIGHTLY messing up my alignment.

So is there some unavoidable issue where all fonts have slight padding around them no matter what you do?

Comment: Any link? If it's that much of a problem, why don't you just use a span tag with a large font size.

Comment: Sorry, I have no specific site I'm building with this issue, it's jsut something I've been working around for a while. It must be a h tag though for obvious reasons.

If you go to your profile page on Facebook and inspect element on your name (span inside h2 tag), you can see 2 or 3px space above and below the text.

Twitter is the same, go to their landing page and inspect the 'Follow your interests' text. There's about 3px above and below.

Answer (score 0):

Don't forget implicit line breaks that can add "silent" space to layouts:

```
<h1>blah blah</h1>[space character here due to line break]
<h1>blah blah</h1>
```

would need to be:

```
<h1>blah blah</h1><h1>blah blah</h1>
```

Comment: Na this is on the actual element. It's just tiny padding, about 2px. If you inspect element in chrome on any heading on most sites you will see what I mean.

Answer (score 0):

Here you go:

**HTML**

```
<div id="blah"> <div style="width:300px; margin:0px auto 0px auto;"><h1 style="color:#000000;font-size:12px; display:inline">This is my heading</h1></div> </div>
```

**CSS**

```
#blah
{
height:50px;
width:100%;
background-color:#B40700;
}
```